# How to implement Easylist filters

Tags: swift, swift4, adblock

I am writing a custom web browser in Swift using WKWebView and I want to add adblocking.

I’ve found the Easylist filter lists like this one: https://easylist.to/easylist/easylist.txt

My question is - how do you implement a list like this. Do you just check all URLs that get loaded and block any with any of these strings in them?

Added bonus question - if you were to do this in swift is there a more intelligent way to do this than looping through and searching for every single one of these strings in the url, that feels like it would take a long time and be very wasteful.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a complete or easy answer for you. However, I can tell you how the files should be parsed, and the docs on that are marked "Unfinished, not for translating" (as of Aug 2019). https://adblockplus.org/filter-cheatsheet  The ABP team also blogged about how to parse that list faster, and it's heavy computer science. https://adblockplus.org/blog/investigating-filter-matching-algorithms